# What is the most modern way to to read a PDF file from Sharepoint online/365 in a C# console application in 2023?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Which SharePoint APIs to use for C# .NET console application?

1. Microsoft Graph API
2. SharePoint REST API v2. Not the v1 SharePoint REST API
3. PnP Framework API.  A successor to the older PnP-Sites-Core API
4. Others ??

The C# console app will run on a user's desktop and the user may or may not be logged into Office 365.  Security would be username/password based and the username would not be the desktop user's Office 365 login.

**It needs to be as bare-bones as possible, using only Microsoft provided APIs and no third-party commercial or open source libraries, no browser plugins, etc..**

The files may belong to a different organization than the user's Office 365 login does.

Eventually, the C# console application will run as a C# Azure function to access PDF files stored on SharePoint folders for different organizations.  The C# Azure function will not always be in the same Office 365 organization as the one owning the SharePoint files.

Help appreciated, since the APIs are all older and it is confusing which one to use.  Graph keeps coming up as the most recent one, but it is 8 years old (released 2015) and we do not want to invest lots of time building around an API which will be retired in 2 years.

Looked at multiple Microsoft SharePoint programming web pages, outside blogs, StackOverflow questions, ...

Each is frozen in time and did not point to what is the modern preferred way to do this.